Rabi Hamiltonian in the presence of a dc magnetic field
I was trying to solve the following Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
{\cal H}=\frac{\hbar\omega_{0}}{2}\sigma_{z}+\frac{B}{2}\cos\left(\omega t\right)\sigma_{x}+B_{dc}\sigma_{x},
\end{equation}
which for $B_{dc}=0$ becomes the Rabi model, a very well-understood and analyzed problem.
However, I haven't found any work on the Rabi model in the presence of an external magnetic field ($B_{dc}$) coupling the two levels.
I taught about going to the diagonal basis with respect to $B_{dc}=0$, but then I ended up with an oscillatory temporal dependence on the diagonal $B_{dc}\cos(\omega t)\sigma_x\rightarrow B_0\cos(\omega t)\sigma_z+B_1\cos(\omega t)\sigma_x$. In principle, I could remove this via a unitary operation, but I am not sure about the physical consequences of it.
In short, has this model been studied before? Does it have a name?
I would be glad if someone could point me in some direction.
Thank you!

Consider first the Hamiltonian $H_0= \frac 12 \hbar \omega_0 \sigma_z$. The eigenvalues are $\pm \frac 12 \hbar \omega_0$ and the eigenvectors $|\uparrow:z\rangle,|\downarrow:z\rangle$. Now, before turning the oscillating field, consider the DC magnetic field on.
The Hamiltonian $H= H_0 + B_{DC}\sigma_x$ could be easily solved like any other 2x2 matrix and the eigenvalues now are
$$
E_\pm= \pm \sqrt{{\hbar^2\omega_0^2\over 4}+B_{DC}^2}
$$
And the eigenvectors $|\uparrow:n\rangle,|\downarrow:n\rangle$ for some direction $n$ determined by the value $B_{DC}$ and $\omega_0$.
By doing some rotation of the reference frame and adjusting the direction $n$ as the new $z$ direction, you recover a situation analogous of what we have without $B_{DC}$. Let's call the unitary representation of this rotation by $U_R$, so we have
$$
U_R( \frac 12 \hbar \omega_0 \sigma_z + B_{DC}\sigma_x) U_R^\dagger = E_+ |\uparrow:n\rangle\!\langle \uparrow:n| + E_- |\downarrow:n\rangle\!\langle\downarrow:n| \equiv |E| \sigma_z'
$$
where $|E|=|E_\pm|$. We could even put $\frac 12 E$ in evidence and write this Hamiltonian as
$$
H_0'= \frac 12 \hbar \omega'_0 \sigma_z'
$$
as the new unperturbed Hamiltonian. So far so good, let's take a look on the new perturbation in this rotated frame. As you said, it will be something like
$$
V(t)=(B_0\sigma_x' + B_1\sigma_z')\cos(\omega t)
$$
But we can deal with it as we deal with a perturbation in $x$ direction with no problem. For example, in first order time-dependent perturbation theory, If the initial state is $|\downarrow:z'\rangle$, the probability to get the state $|\uparrow:z'\rangle$ até time t Will be
$$
P(t) = \frac{1}{\hbar^2} \left|\int_0^t e^{i\omega_0't}\langle\downarrow:z'|V(\tau)|\uparrow:z'\rangle d\tau\right|^2.
$$
You can see that in the r.h.s., the term $B_1\sigma_z'$ does not contribute, and the result would be the same as if $B_1=0$. So even if the $z$ component contributes, it will be in second order, and usually we neglect it.

So in resume, applying constant fields only accounts as rotations in the system of coordinates (and changing of the eigenvalues, like a displacement of the ressonant lines).

Thanks @Ruffolo. As I already wrote in my post, I have done this rotation.
The problem is that this leads to cos()→0cos()+1cos(), which is a different problem than the Rabi model due to the diagonal oscillating term.

It could seen different, but it is just a rotated Rabi problem. What we call $x,y,z$ is completely arbitrary and there is no physical consequences of it, just mathematical complexities. I'll wrote it in my answer with more details

Thank you for taking the time to write that. I went even further and removed the diagonal $\cos$ via unitary transformation $\textrm{exp}\left[-i\frac{B_{0}}{2\hbar\omega}\sin\left(\omega t\right)\sigma_{z}\right]$, mapping this back to the Rabi model. However, I was wondering whether all the physics remains the same. For example, if we simulate this Hamiltonian with Lindblad dissipators, I have to rewrite the Lindblad equation within this new basis. As a consequence, this would change the functional form of the Lindbladian, and I assume the physics would change. Any thoughts on this?

Unfortunately, I'm not familiarized with Lindbladians. My intuition tells me that nothing changes, but maybe I'm wrong. But this is an excellent question, and I think that maybe you should ask it!
